# Local Repository With Git Tower

Tags: git, laravel, laravel-5, git-tower

I'm really trying to learn to be better at using git-tower but I have not been successful yet. I am having an issue. I currently have a Laravel 5 project that comes with a couple of git files but I am not seeing a .git folder so I went to my list of repositories and clicked on Create to make it a local repository since I'm a little late doing so for this project and went I browse to the root folder of my application it adds it to the list of repositories but when I click on it to open it, it says repository not found please provide new path.

Can someone explain what I need to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's Tobias from the Tower team. Please get in touch via support[at]git-tower[dot].com and we'll see if we can help!

First idea already: have you tried switching the Git binary used by Tower? You can do so by opening Tower's preferences on the "Git Config" tab. There, you should try using the system binary (/usr/bin/git).

Comment: I was able to fix the issue. Thank you.